# How do the search box stick to the toolbar in onsen-ui?

Tags: onsen-ui

In my page I have an `ons-toolbar` on top and an `ons-list` in the page. The first list-item contains a search box, when the user scrolls down the list the search box will go up with other elements, is there any way to make the search box sticks to to the top of the page or bottom of toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
ons-toolbar ~ .page__content{
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.search-bar {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
.after-search-bar {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Your html should look like this

```
<ons-page>

    <ons-toolbar>
          <!--your tool bar-->
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div class="search-bar">
        <input type="search" class="search-input" style="width: 96%; margin: 6px auto 6px auto;" placeholder="Search">    
    </div>

    <div class="after-search-bar">
        <ons-list>
            <ons-list-item>
                <!--your list items-->
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </div>

</ons-page>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solved the problem, the search-bar div sticks to the top but when I scroll the content of div (ie. search box) will move with the other contents

Comment: Hmmm what do you mean by "the content of div (ie. search box)"? I tested the above code and the search bar sticks to the top while the list content is scrolled.

Comment: Tamura: RezaRahmati is correct with his comment. Eventhough is works in the browser, it is not working in the phone while testing. I have tested with iphone.  The image looks like the following. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnvis1cvwbw5het/File%2029-1-16%2C%206%2025%2004%20%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B1%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8D.png?dl=0  . Please let me know if you need more information.